# How to manage a session in a same domain but different directory

Tags: php, session

Let's say I have www.example.com for hosting multiple PHP projects that completely unrelated e.g. www.example.com/app1 , www.example.com/app2. Every projects mades by different person so app1 owner cannot modify app2 project.

The problem is when app1 login/logout , it affects on app2. So, How do I separate a session for different project ? or I need to set a root path at somewhere...

Now my project has only

```
session_start();
```

at the top of every page.

P.S. Sorry for bad English.

Comment: if you really want to separate them see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41164225/4907187. but, alternatively you could use the same session but different variable names for each app

Comment: I cannot use same sessions because each directory manage by different person.  I use this website for hosting entire projects in a class at my college.
Can I use  session_name  at the top of a page ?

Comment: yes, of course. make sure to set different session name for each app `session_name($string); session_start();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the possibility to use subdomains (app1.exapmple.com and app2.example.com), that is automatically solved.